Why are my terminals not found when I do an automatic scan in TwinCAT?
I have a C6025-0000 that I want to use as a PLC. After connecting to the C6025, I want to scan (menu TwinCAT > Scan, or right-click on IO > Devices > Scan) for terminals. But I can't find any EtherCAT devices. Why is this?

Why close this? There is no better community to post these questions.

Can you share how your problem is related to programming? You haven't included any code so far, and the answer you've posted looks highly related to hardware configuration

It is true that is more of a hardware configuration question. I thought this would be the best place to post a question, since all twincat related questions are posted here. I don't know of any other community where it would fit.

You first need to install a TwinCAT Ethernet driver on the Ethernet adapters on the industrial pc before you can scan for devices. If you buy a CX series PLC, these drivers are already installed, so you don't have to do this anymore. The C6025 and other industrial PC's are not primarily used as a controller, but more as an 'edge' device to connect a display with a HMI for example, as shown below.

Installing TwinCAT real-time driver
To install a TwinCAT real-time driver:

Make sure a TwinCAT runtime is installed on the PC.

Remote desktop onto it, or connect a screen to the industrial PC.

Open the explorer and go to C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System and open TcRteInstall.exe. Note: this is on the industrial PC or whatever device you want to connect some terminals to.

A window opens with the available ethernet adapters and compatible ones. On the C6025 there are three, and in this screenshot there is just one.


Select an ethernet port (for example the eth-laptop in this case) and click on install.

Wait a second and then the ethernet port should show up under one of the two "Installed and ready to use ..." categories, as shown here for the three ports on my C6025.



For more information see InfoSys.
